# Typo3 Generate link in controller

Tags: hyperlink, controller, typo3

I'm facing with issue like this : 
I'm trying to get uri in controller. I created an API and return link via JSON. In view I can do this

```
<f:link.action action="list" arguments="{location : location, myId : location.uid}">>&nbsp;</f:link.action>
```

But how to generate above link in controller?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried `$this->uriBuilder->uriFor()`, which will get you the URI, and you could come up your own link as you needed.

Comment: Thanks. I tried like this :
$uri = $this->uriBuilder->uriFor('list', array('location' => 'location', 'myId'=>$value->getUid()));
In view, I just need these information.
And it returns 
tx_locations_locationsfe[location]=location&tx_locations_locationsfe[myId]=95&tx_locations_locationsfe[action]=list&tx_locations_locationsfe[controller]=Location&cHash=77440a3c879ae683b14ed4a8f91c9099
But it wrong. and I need it returns friendly url like in view.

Comment: OK, you may look at `$this->redirect()` then, and get the idea how the Controller creates the URI. I think your problem is the realurl didn't work because of the page uid was not set.

Comment: Thanks so much. I solved the problem.
The reason is realurl does not work.

Comment: Glad to hear that :)